# Myehereumwallet displays wrong amount

Tags: mist, synchronization, ethereum-classic, myetherwallet

I have 35 ETH. Etherscan shows this correctly, but MyEtherWallet displays 0.013 ETC. I did nothing. I just downloded Mist and started syncing.

Comment: Please, put the solution on the answer not in the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved :) MyEtherWallet was connected via epool.io to an ETC node not an ETH node.